# trying to make paths work - attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Tags: python, pytest

I can't make this work..

My structure is:

```
program_name/

  __init__.py
  setup.py

  src/
    __init__.py

    Process/
        __init__.py
        thefile.py

  tests/
     __init__.py
     thetest.py
```

thetest.py:

```
from ..src.Process.thefile.py import sth
```

Running: `pytest ./tests/thetest.py` from `program_name` gives :

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

I tried also other approaches but i am receiving various errors.

But I would expect for the above to work.

Comment: Have you tried `import Process.thefile` ? I am assuming that you are trying to run the program from a top-level folder

Comment: @ssm:It gives 'No module named..'

Comment: try `from Process import thefile`

Comment: @ssm:It still gives no module named.

Comment: ha ha, sorry, my bad. `from src.Process import thefile` This one should work ...

Comment: @ssm:It gives " No module named 'tests.src'"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package**

States that you're trying to use relative import in the module, which are to be used for packages i.e. to make it a package add `__init__.py` and call the `thetest.py` from some file outside the package.
Directly running `thetest.py` from interpreter won't work.

> Relative imports require that the module which uses them is being
>   imported itself either as package module.

---

**Suggestion 1**:

The current `tests` directory has a `__init__.py` file but that doesn't allow you to run it as a module (via shell) - to make your current (relative) import work, you need to import it in an external (to package) file/module - let's create a `main.py` (can name it anything you like):

```
    main.py
    program_name/
      __init__.py
      setup.py
      src/
        __init__.py
        Process/
            __init__.py
            thefile.py
      tests/
         __init__.py
         thetest.py
```

src/Process/**thefile.py**:

```
s = 'Hello world'
```

tests/**thetest.py**:

```
from ..src.Process.thefile import s

print s
```

**main.py**:

```
from program_name.tests.thetest import s
```

Executing **main.py**:

```
[nahmed@localhost ~]$ python main.py 
Hello world
```

---

**Suggestion 2**:

Execute the file just above root dir i.e. one level up the `program_name/` , in the following fashion:

```
[nahmed@localhost ~]$ python -m program_name.tests.thetest
Hell World
```

---

**P.S**. relative imports are for packages, not modules.

Answer (score 8):

Just solved a similar problem with a lot of googling.
Here's two solutions without changing the existing file structor:

### 1

The way to import module from parent folder `from ..src.Process.thefile.py import sth` is called "relative import".

It's only supported when launching as a package from the top-level package. In your case, that is launching command line from the directory which contains **`program_name/`** and type (for win environment)

```
python -m program_name.tests.thetest
```

or simply (useful for many pytest files):

```
python -m pytest
```

### 2

Otherwise -- when trying to run a script alone or from a non top-level package --
you could manually add directory to the PYTHONPATH at run time.

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append(path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))))
from src.Process.thefile import s
```

Try the first one first see if it's compatiable with the pytest framework. Otherwise the second one should always solve the problem.

Reference ([How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/how-to-fix-attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py))

Comment: Great answer! Note: with solution 1) you don't have to specify the pytest file (especially useful when you have many pytest files). You can simply do `python -m pytest`

Answer (score 1):

When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from. 
you can use *sys.path* to include different locations

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import thefile
```

Comment: It gives, no module named..Also, I want to avoid to use sys path if possible.

Comment: how about imp module import imp
foo = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
foo.MyClass()