# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package with a grandparent directory (relative imports question again)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the file "Query.py" trying to import the class SqlQuery from the file "database.py" which is located up two levels & then down one in another directory (also called "database"). Then the import statement I *expect* to work looks like this: `from ...database.database import SqlQuery`

But that gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Roland/dir1/2020/Indeed-Scraper/scraper/classes/Query.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ....database.database import SqlQuery
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

*since I understand way you run the file can be important*, I am trying to run Query.py using my PyCharm IDE

This is way harder than I expected it to be!

Here are the relevant parts of my file structure:

```
project_name/
    __init__.py
    database/
        __init__.py
        database.py
    scraper/
        __init__.py
        classes/
            __init__.py
            Query.py
```

And here are the various things I've tried: (this code sits at the top of Query.py, one line above the `from ...database.database import SqlQuery` statement)

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('...'))  # attempt 1
sys.path.insert(0, '')  # attempt 2
sys.path.append("...")  # attempt 3 - I think it is strange that adding "..." to the path did not work?
```

I did Google & check out various StackOverflow threads about this. I either didn't find a satisfactory answer (I can't believe I need to write `sys.path.append(anything)` in the best solution) or I didn't understand a solution when I found it. I've been [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42689226/trying-to-make-paths-work-attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166821/valueerror-attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package), [to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022220/attempted-relative-import-beyond-toplevel-package), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981741/i-got-an-error-attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package), among other places.

I'm also reading the top-level answer in the popular post, ["Relative imports for the billionth time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) and I understand that:

- My Query.py file is exectued as a "top-level script" when I execute it directly in my PyCharm IDE.
- "database.py" is loaded as a module since it comes from an import statement.
- "Scripts can't import relative", the author says. "Relative imports are only for use within module files."

...and so, while the thread was informative, I just don't see any answers that seem to be solutions to my problem. I really don't want to post this since it must be a duplicate of some kind, but I haven't found an answer. What gives, Python? Why is importing so hard?

Footnote: Currently the `__init__.py` files are empty. Should I be filling them with something to make relative imports easier?

Comment: One thing I do to avoid issues with imports is just make a `setup.py` for your project. Then run `pip install -e .`.

Comment: Something like what's talked about in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471994/what-is-setup-py i.e. in the 2nd answer, "Using setup.py" and "Creating setup.py"

Comment: Yup! That explains it nicely.

Comment: Also, the `__init__.py` files don't need anything in them. They are there so Python knowns what's a module. You can put stuff in them if you want. A common thing to do is import everything into your root `__init__.py` so everything is importable from the root module. E.g.  `from foo import bar` instead of `from foo.baz.bim.bop import bar`.

Comment: so I made a setup.py file, uploaded it to PyPI, did pip install indeed-scraper (the name of my pkg) and then... ```import indeed-scraper``` did not work. I tried again setting the ```name``` value in ```setuptools.setup()``` to ```indeedScraper``` instead of ```indeed-scraper``` in case the dash was tripping things up in the import statement. Nada. After ```pip install indeedScraper```, importing "indeedScraper" gave me ```ModuleNotFoundError```. I've made progress but I'm still stuck!

Comment: I should've been more specific. You don't actually have to upload it to PyPi for setup.py to work. Just go to the root of your project and run `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py install`. That will do the same thing as installing it from PyPi

Comment: And for the name thing, Python modules can't have a dash in the name.

Comment: You might be missing an __init__.py in your scraper directory

Comment: Thank you Kimbo but I do have ```__init__.py``` there, just didn't list it

Comment: Oh okay. If you're code is open source, you could post a link to your project and I could take a look a little later today

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208886/discussion-between-kimbo-and-roly-poly).